# Visual Studio SQL Server table not updating

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and I'm following a tutorial to create a login page. However when switching from `nchar(10)` to `uniqueidentifier` or even increasing the character limit to 50, I can't update the table and I also can't save it. This is the error I receive below can anyone help me resolve this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] 
(
    [Id]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [Username] NCHAR (20) NULL,
    [Password] NCHAR (20) NULL,
    [Email]    NCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Country]  NCHAR (20) NULL
);
```

Altering [dbo].[Table]...

Error:

> SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
>
> SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] ALTER COLUMN [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL;
>
> An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Comment: your data type do not match. use Guid data type for the property in C# that corresponds to Id in your sql

Comment: When you debug, what is the value for the ID column you are trying to update?

Comment: try passing a Guid.NewGuid() to your Id but i don't recommend this, since you can change the property of your Id from Sql,. Set the RowGuid property to true.. then you don't have to pass an ID from ASP.NET when creating

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with

```
(
[Id]   DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
 ...
)
```

Comment: Could you explain how `NEWSEQUENTIALID` will resolve the issue?

Comment: [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786(v=sql.110).aspx)